# How do you guarantee all the ??? are filled out when you Magic Lens a monster?

Tags: tales-of-symphonia-hd

How do you guarantee all the ??? are filled out when you Magic Lens a monster?

I know I Lensed a Golem, since I have its HP, TP, Atk, Exp, Gald, and Def... But I don't know what I can steal from it, or its Location, (Martel Temple)...

Does Lensing twice guarantee getting all the info when you receive the Monster List after the Sylvarant Base?

Comment: Apparently only Raine can use Magic Lens to see the location of the monster on the Monster List